# How can i pass an azure cli variable to Azure Devops variables?

Tags: azure

I have written an Azure  cli task in Azure Devops as below

$vnetid = $(az network vnet show -n $vnet -g $(rg) --query id --output tsv)

I want to output the $vnetid to the Azure Devops Variables so it can be used in another task how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can simply do

```
Write-Output("##vso[task.setvariable variable=vnetid;]$$vnetid")
```

Comment: I have 2 tasks one is to get the subnet ref and vnet id, these then need to go into variables which can be passed to the next task. Task 2 is to deploy an ARM template and in the "overridde parameters section" i want to use those variables obtained from Task 1. I can safely use $(variable) in some of the parameters but for the vnet and subnet i need those obtained from TASK 1 Azure Cli and use them in this task